# Generate four type-4 GUIDs for me

Tags: code-golf, random, generation

The type 4 GUID is described by Wikipedia, quoth:

> Version 4 UUIDs use a scheme relying only on random numbers. This algorithm sets the version number (4 bits) as well as two reserved bits. All other bits (the remaining 122 bits) are set using a random or pseudorandom data source. Version 4 UUIDs have the form xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx where x is any hexadecimal digit and y is one of 8, 9, A, or B (e.g., f47ac10b-58cc-4372-a567-0e02b2c3d479).

Write a program that loads 488 bits (61 bytes) of cryptographic quality randomness and output them as 4 GUIDs using the format quoted above.

- Do not waste randomness.

  - All random bits must appear in the encoded output.
  - All encoded bits must be traceable to either a single random bit or one of the six fixed bits that must appear in each GUID.
- Use the cryptographic quality random number generator supplied by your language's standard library.
- Do not use a library or external resource that generates GUIDs.
- The hyphens must appear in their correct positions.
- The fixed bits of this form of GUID must appear in their correct positions.
- You may use a standard library function designed to output a GUID from 128 bits.
- Normal code-golf rules apply.

For example...

```
> gentype4
6FA53B63-E7EA-4461-81BE-9CD106A1AFF8
856970E9-377A-458E-96A7-43F587724573
E4F859AC-0004-4AA1-A3D2-AECB527D1D24
766811C5-0C44-4CC8-8C30-E3D6C7C6D00B
```

Update:
I asked for *four* GUIDs in order to allow a whole number of random bytes to be gathered without leaving any remainder. I also specified that none of the bits should be wasted in order to avoid the easy answer of getting 16 random bytes and dropping the 4 in. (No, shift the other bits along first.)

Update 2:
If your language's standard library doesn't have a cryptographic quality random byte generator, you may instead assume that there is a 61 byte file present with enough random bytes for you to use when the program starts. The file should be called "/dev/urandom" or another filename with 12 characters.

Comment: If my language doesn't have a way to request a certain number of random bits/bytes, but can get a random number from 0 to n-1 using something like `random(n)`, can I just use `random(1<<k)` as a way to get k random bits? Also, is it ok to get them in small pieces (e.g. 4 or 2 bits at a time) through multiple calls?

Comment: I was hoping to see how different languages can access cryptographic quality randomness. I'll add an exception for those languages without such means.

Comment: Well, now you're assuming it can read external files :p What I could use is a sequence of numbers (separated by space) given through the standard input.. but maybe I'm asking too much and should just not participate (in that language). And an unrelated note: the wikipedia quote refers to UUIDs, not GUIDs.

Comment: A close duplicate: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/20363

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 338 bytes

```php
<?php $r=openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(61);$b="";$s="substr";for($i=0;$i<61;)$b.=str_pad(decbin(ord($r[$i++])),8,0,0);function p($B,$L){return str_pad(dechex(bindec($B)),$L,0,0);}for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)echo p($s($b,$p=122*$i,32),8)."-".p($s($b,$p+32,16),4)."-4".p($s($b,$p+48,12),3)."-".p("10".$s($b,$p+60,14),4)."-".p($s($b,$p+74,48),12)."\n";
```

### Some output

```
> php 32309.min.php
635fa088-4a66-47fc-9e50-2ccb2445b643
6e5c23c7-ba16-427e-960b-5316980ce4e3
fdb570ca-2e5e-4594-ab2e-db8446599b8f
203f2538-b5f4-47f0-89ac-012ca14b2f99
> php 32309.min.php
a6981255-0ab2-4d82-aab4-d1c64d2bb7eb
c348e728-f817-45d2-9bbf-b40426baa461
9b2baed2-e58b-41ef-a6fb-57e96db74a68
63e464e7-ab55-4e2a-a2a0-abdc535481dc
> php 32309.min.php
af7e68d3-b3ed-4e19-85b2-280270f746c6
0a86c610-8d0c-4c0a-bafe-44a6886d71f8
98c742b8-6a3b-47ff-97c7-ccab70d79a3c
59a93afc-ff81-4c97-a57b-72f0de384acb
> php 32309.min.php
72b352fc-0174-4051-969e-cacc0adbf941
50e4f859-76fe-45f6-baf5-d5fcceb41f72
5a18408e-6e7e-43a6-bd71-09d22a0fbf14
ae5a1391-5367-467e-8ecc-785ca72cbf95
```

### Ungolfed

```php
<?php
$r = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(61);
$b = "";
$s = "substr";
for($i=0 ; $i<61 ;) $b .= str_pad(decbin(ord($r[$i++])), 8, 0, 0);

function p($B, $L) {
    return str_pad(dechex(bindec($B)), $L, 0, 0);
}

for($i=0 ; $i<4 ; $i++) {
    echo p($s($b, 122*$i, 32), 8)."-";
    echo p($s($b, 122*$i+32, 16), 4)."-4";
    echo p($s($b, 122*$i+48, 12), 3)."-";
    echo p("10".$s($b, 122*$i+60, 14), 4)."-";
    echo p($s($b, 122*$i+74, 48), 12)."\n";
}
```

Comment: `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`? That's.. verbose. PHP keeps amazing me - in the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

### J - 114 bytes

I took the simplest approach available. The function takes amount of GUID's required (you could replace the `]` near the end with `4:` to make it return 4 always) and outputs that many of them, separated by newlines.

Edit: I missed that no generated bits must go to waste... This answer doesn't comply and I don't know how to make it to.

```
f=:[:}.(,LF,(x@8:,'-',x@4:,'-4',x,'-',('89AB'{~?@4:),x,'-',(x=:'0123456789ABCDEF'{~?@$&16)@(12"_))@3:)^:(]`(''"_))
```

If an extra newline is allowed after the output, this could be written in **111 bytes**.

```
f=:(,LF,~(x@8:,'-',x@4:,'-4',x,'-',('89AB'{~?@4:),x,'-',(x=:'0123456789ABCDEF'{~?@$&16)@(12"_))@3:)^:(]`(''"_))
```

Example:

```
   f 4
B23B10E3-6593-40F7-A5B0-D25A2763D781
3901709C-654E-4AF0-B23E-7252E859D35B
91E8D566-8E84-48CD-9B9D-EFC4E3F62C4E
F4578389-097C-4C38-A3C0-31EABFDCD630
   f 5
AF234012-8A9F-47A3-9BF5-4B28AF580E9C
A3FE1785-8B40-44E9-8D69-CFF1BE06AC06
84A2CEB9-744F-4B86-B37F-747D0FD3F3FC
0FD8B7A6-9642-42C3-89ED-DB4A35D83CF8
4F860D9B-6E20-4AF8-B6BF-0F8CB307B9B0
```

Comment: @billpg This version generates a 32-bit integer for each necessary hexadecimal digit (for everything but the 4, `-` and linefeed). Is that okay?

Answer (score 1):

## Golfscript, 75

Fixed now!

```
{{'0123456789ABCDEF'{.,rand>1<}:|~}:&8*'-':^&&&&^4&&&^'89AB'|&&&^{&}12*n}4*
```

#### Output example:

```
>ruby golfscript.rb p.gs
140BC879-EAC4-4170-B349-A616523458DB
E26B34A4-8E86-4508-9EE5-3C76BF7456B6
89F9B995-CC9E-4EF0-AA25-70703B80AF82
5F6A513C-9E97-45A4-A9D1-E9D3DF71EF99

>ruby golfscript.rb p.gs
38D7A76B-BEEB-4C98-A148-D1EA8C31E85F
807373E4-5CFE-4953-9D5E-671205EE1E8F
8BD88B76-5890-4543-9787-2753AB15D24B
CD7DF25F-632B-4902-A46C-A1E10BE83EC5
```

You can test it yourself [here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=e3snMDEyMzQ1Njc4OUFCQ0RFRid7LixyYW5kPjE8fTp8fn06JjgqJy0nOl4mJiYmXjQmJiZeJzg5QUInfCYmJl57Jn0xMipufTQq).

Comment: That bug is pretty.

Comment: Was pretty atleast.

Comment: Is "rand" in GS a cryptographic quality random number generator?

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 287 bytes

```
from random import choice
s="0123456789abcdef"
def gen4():
  for i in range(4):
    m,n="",""
    l = []
    d = choice(s[8:12])
    for k in range(30):
      l.append(choice(s))
    m="".join(l)
    n=m[:12]+"4"+m[12:15]+d+m[15:]
    print(n[:8]+"-"+n[8:12]+"-"+n[12:16]+"-"+n[16:20]+"-"+n[20:])
```

There's already a Python answer, but that just used .uuid, so here's one without it. Wish i could get it shorter though.

Still beat PHP :P

Answer (score 0):

### Python (85)

```
import os,uuid
for i in [1]*4:print uuid.UUID(os.urandom(16).encode('hex'),version=4)
```

[os.urandom(n): Return a string of n random bytes suitable for cryptographic use.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.urandom)

I assume generating more than 488 bits is ok?

Comment: Standard library function is part of the library that comes with your language. `os` and `uuid` both are part of it.

Comment: I added the "Don't waste any bits" rule because I wanted to see some bit fiddling. Just being able to drop in the 4 wiping out other bits seemed too simple a task.

Comment: That's also why I specified *four* GUIDs to be output, so you'd have a whole number of random bytes to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2 - 188 / 182

This should obey the requirements faithfully:

```
import os
a=(ord(x)>>i&3for i in(0,2,4,6)for x in os.urandom(61))
h=lambda n:eval('"%X"%(a.next()*4+a.next())+'*n+'"-"')
exec'print h(8)+h(4)+"4"+h(3)+"%X"%(8+a.next())+h(3)+h(12)[:-1];'*4
```

If python's UUID is acceptable for outputting a nicely-formatted uuid from a 32-digit hex string, then this version has 182 bytes:

```
import os,uuid
a=(ord(x)>>i&3for i in(0,2,4,6)for x in os.urandom(61))
exec('s='+'"%X"%(a.next()*4+a.next())+'*30+'"";print uuid.UUID(s[3:15]+"4"+s[:3]+"%X"%(8+a.next())+s[15:]);')*4
```

`a` is a generator comprehension that gives 2 bits at a time from an initial source of 61 random bytes.

Thanks TheRare for tips

Comment: You don't need to set x in `t`, just return it. `for i in range(n):s+="%X"%(t()*4+t())` could be written `exec's+="%X"%(t()*4+t());'*n` and thus function `h` could be written in one line. You can use the same trick in the following loop too, just replace `n` by 4.

Comment: Whoops, yes you do need to set it. Sorry! The rest still works though.

Comment: @TheRare `exec` also seems to interfere with `global`, but still there is something to gain, thanks for reminding me about it

Comment: Ah, sorry. I completely forgot that `global` causes it to break. What if you changed it to something like this (didn't check if it's shorted, but global `s` is not needed): `def h(n):s='';exec's+="%X"%(t()*4+t());'*4;return s+'-'<LINEFEED HERE>print'\n'.join(h(8)+h(4)+'4'+h(3)+"%X"%(8+t())+h(3)+h(12)for _ in 1,2,3,4)`

Comment: Or even `h=lambda n:''.join("%X"%(t()*4+t())for _ in[0]*n)+'-';print'\n'.join(h(8)+h(4)+'4'+h(3)+"%X"%(8+t())+h(3)+h(12)for _ in[0]*4)` (both are untested)

Comment: You could replace the `1,2,3,4` by `[0]*4`, come to think of it and remove the space in front of it. (I updated the comment above).

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript (ES6) - <s>177</s> <s>163</s> 158

Removed `.toUpperCase()`, replaced `substring` with `substr` and `substr(0,3)` to `substr(1)`

```
function f(){g=()=>(((1+Math.random())*0x10000)|0).toString(16).substr(1);for(i=0;i<4;i++)alert((g()+g()+"-"+g()+"-4"+g().substr(1)+"-"+g()+"-"+g()+g()+g()))}
```

EcmaScript 5 version of the above script:

```
function f(){function g(){return (((1+Math.random())*0x10000)|0).toString(16).substr(1)}for(i=0;i<4;i++)alert((g()+g()+"-"+g()+"-4"+g().substr(1)+"-"+g()+"-"+g()+g()+g()))}
```

Comment: Doesn't `f=x=>` work as the function definition? I've never used ES6 though.

Comment: @TheRare Nope..

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp

### SBCL, 223

```
(define-alien-routine("arc4random_uniform"a)int(u
int))(labels((g(n)(a(expt 2 n)))(h()(g 16)))(dotimes(i 4)(format
t"~4,'0X~4,'0X-~4,'0X-~4,'0X-~4,'0X-~4,'0X~4,'0X~4,'0X~%"(h)(h)(h)(+
16384(g 12))(+ 32768(g 14))(h)(h)(h))))
```

### CLISP, 299

```
(use-package :ffi)(def-call-out
a(:name"arc4random_uniform")(:arguments(u int))(:return-type
int)(:language :c)(:library :default))(labels((g(n)(a(expt 2
n)))(h()(g 16)))(dotimes(i 4)(format
t"~4,'0X~4,'0X-~4,'0X-~4,'0X-~4,'0X-~4,'0X~4,'0X~4,'0X~%"(h)(h)(h)(+
16384(g 12))(+ 32768(g 14))(h)(h)(h))))
```

### About arc4random_uniform(3)

Both of these call the C function [arc4random_uniform(3)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=arc4random_uniform&sektion=3&manpath=OpenBSD%20Current&arch=i386&format=html) in BSD libc. Some systems do not have this function.

Beware that my declaration of arc4random_uniform(3) is **wrong**. The correct declaration is

```
u_int32_t arc4random_uniform(u_int32_t);
```

where `u_int32_t` is an old BSDism for an unsigned 32-bit integer. (The standard type in C99 is `uint32_t` without the first underscore.) My **wrong** declaration is

```
int arc4random_uniform(int);
```

where `int` is a signed 32-bit integer. (I know systems where `int` only has 16 bits, but I would not run Lisp there.) I am wrong to use signed for unsigned, but my program works because I only pass small non-negative integers. In code golf, `int` is shorter than `unsigned-int` in SBCL or `uint` in CLISP.

To use arc4random_uniform(3) in Lisp, I define a Lisp function `a`. Here it is in SBCL:

```
; (use-package :sb-alien)  ; SBCL does this by default!
(define-alien-routine ("arc4random_uniform" a)
  int       ; return type
  (u int))  ; argument named u
```

And in CLISP:

```
(use-package :ffi)
(def-call-out a
  (:name "arc4random_uniform")
  (:arguments (u int))
  (:return-type int)
  (:language :c)
  (:library :default))
```

CLISP has two languages, `:c` for traditional K&R C and `:stdc` for C89, but I find no difference, so I use the shorter name.

Now `(a u)` returns a random integer at least 0 and less than *u*. If *u* is 2<sup>*n*</sup>, then I get exactly *n* bits. For example, `(a (expt 2 14)` provides 14 bits. Because of my wrong declaration, *u* must be less than 2<sup>31</sup>. If I want 32 bits, I may call `(a 16)` twice.

### Rest of program

```
; after defining A
(labels ((g (n) (a (expt 2 n)))
         (h () (g 16)))
  (dotimes (i 4)
    (format t
            "~4,'0X~4,'0X-~4,'0X-~4,'0X-~4,'0X-~4,'0X~4,'0X~4,'0X~%"
            (h) (h) (h) (+ 16384 (g 12)) (+ 32768 (g 14)) (h) (h) (h))))
```

I define two local functions. `(g n)` generates *n* random bits. `(expt 2 n)` is much shorter than a left shift: `1<<n` in C would become `(let((v 0))(setf(ldb(byte 1 n)v)1)v)` in Common Lisp!

`(h)` is an alias for `(g 16)`. This alias costs 13 characters: 11 in `(h()(g 16))`, plus 2 to upgrade `flet` to `labels`, because *h* needs *g* in scope. Each call to `(h)` saves 3 characters, and I have 6 calls, so I save 18 after I spend 13.

When formatting each GUID, `(+ 16384(g 12))` is shorter than `(logior #x4000 (g 12)` and `(+ 32768(g 14))` is shorter than `(logior #x8000 (g 14))`.

One can generate the long format string `"~4,'0X~4,'0X-~4,'0X-~4,'0X-~4,'0X-~4,'0X~4,'0X~4,'0X~%"` (56 characters) with the expression `(format()"~{~A~}~~%"(mapcar(lambda(e)(if e(format()"~~4,'0X")'-))'(t t()t()t()t()t t t)))` (89 characters), but the literal string is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 41 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
4F30F15ÝΩh}J•2,ÈĆ•13в£'-4и4DL7+hΩ‚.ιÁ.ιJ,
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fxM3YwM3Q9PDccyszar0eNSwy0jnccaQNyDA0vrDp0GJ1XZMLO0xcfMy1M86tfNQwS@/czsONQMJL5/9/AA)

**Explanation:**

```python
4F                  # Loop 4 times:
  30F               #  Inner loop 30 times:
     15Ý            #   Push the list [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
        Ω           #   Pop and push a random integer from this list
         h          #   Convert the integer to hexadecimal
          }J        #  After the inner loop: join the characters on the stack together
•2,ÈĆ•              #  Push compressed integer 40106286
      13в           #  Convert it to base-13 as list: [8,4,0,3,0,3,12]
         £          #  Split the string into parts of that size
                    #   i.e. "FBA4C1C6FE22479659019DA439B7D6"
                    #    → ["FBA4C1C6","FE22","","479","","659","019DA439B7D6"]
'-4и               '#  Push a list of 4 "-"s: ["-","-","-","-"]
    4               #  Push a 4
     DL             #  Duplicate it to create the list [1,2,3,4]
       7+           #  Add 7 to each: [8,9,10,11]
         h          #  Convert each to hexadecimal: [8,9,"A","B"]
          Ω         #  Pop and push a random value from this list
                    #   i.e. "B"
           ‚        #  Pair it together with the 4
            .ι      #  Interleave it with the list of "-": ["-",4,"-","B","-","-"]
              Á     #  Rotate it once towards the right: ["-","-",4,"-","B","-"]
               .ι   #  Interleave it with the earlier created list
                    #   → ["FBA4C1C6","-","FE22","-","",4,"479","-","","B","659","-","019DA439B7D6"]
                 J  #  Join this list together to a string
                    #   → "FBA4C1C6-FE22-4479-B659-019DA439B7D6"
                  , #  And output it with trailing newline
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to compress large integers?* and *How to compress integer lists?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•2,ÈĆ•` is `40106286` and `•2,ÈĆ•13в` is `[8,4,0,3,0,3,12]`.

Without the requirement that no random bits must go to waste, this could have been **36 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)**, by utilizing the builtin `ǝ` (based on [my answer here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177721/52210)):

```
4FŽΣÌvy4*F15ÝΩh}'-}J¨4DL7+hΩ‚Ž5Ā2äǝ,
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ATsAxP9vc2FiaWX//zRGxb3Oo8OMdnk0KkYxNcOdzqlofSctfUrCqDRETDcraM6p4oCaxb01xIAyw6THnSz//w)

Answer (score 0):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/) 1.4.1, 114 bytes

```python
from random import*
for C in[->f'{randrange(16**_):0{_}x}']*4:print(C 8,C 4,'4'+C 3,choice'89ab'+C 3,C 12,sep='-')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85Pzs8rLfn/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocaXlFyk4K2TmRevapalXgySBOD1Vw9BMSyte08qgOr62olY9VsvEqqAoM69Ew1nBQsdZwURH3URd21nBWCc5Iz8zOVXdwjIxCSLgrGBopFOcWmCrrquu@f8/AA)

This works on the old version on TIO, for newer versions you might need parentheses around `'89ab'`.